# How do I get LILO to boot on cloned hard drive?

Tags: livecd, cloning, lilo

I have a really old hard drive with DOS and Linux partitions with LILO as the boot loader. I want a clone of this hard drive that works exactly like the original.

I made a clone using Knoppix and dd_rescue. When I plug in the newly cloned drive, the LILO boot loader stops at "LI" meaning LILO failed at that point.

Is this because I need to actually run the LILO command on the LILO partition on the new hard drive before it will work? If so, how do I do that from a live CD?

**Update:**

Booted from Knoppix live CD:
[image: fdisk]
[image: chroot]

I don't know what "open /dev/hda: Device not configured" is telling me.

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52790/22222). It deals with `grub` but you can just use `lilo` instead. The main idea is setting up a `chroot` environment.

Comment: @terdon That is the point I'm getting to. After I type 'lilo' to run it, I get "open /dev/hda: Device not configured". In lilo.conf; boot=/dev/hda. Does this error mean something isn't mounted correctly?

Comment: Yes, your disk is almost certainly now called `dev/sdX` and lili.conf is still pointing to `/dev/hda`. If you boot a live cd and run `lilo` from a `chroot` environment as I describe in my linked answer, it should work.

Comment: @terdon I have ran it from the chroot environment you described and I get the "open /dev/hda: Device not configured" message. Do I need to change the entries in lilo.conf from '/dev/hda' to '/dev/sda'? I don't understand what that error is telling me.

Comment: OK, then please [edit] your question to show what you did, including the output of `sudo fdisk -l`, the exact commands you used to make the `chroot` environment and the contents of your `lilo.conf`.

Comment: @terdon I added this information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the exact details but for a few years now, the kernel has been treating IDE hard drives as SCSI. So, what used to be `/dev/hda` in your old system will be `/dev/sda` in your new one. This is simply the [naming convention](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/devices.html) for SCSI drives. In any case, your new drive is almost certainly not a classic IDE drive but either SCSI or eSATA or one of the more modern protocols.

Your system, therefore, currently has no `/dev/hda`, what it has, as you can see in the output of `fdisk -l`, is `/dev/sda`. Therefore, for `lilo` to work, you need to change all occurrences of `hda` with `sda` in your `lilo.conf` and then run lilo again:

```
 sed -i.bak 's/hda/sda/g'
 lilo
```

The `sed` command will make the necessary replacement and also create a backup of your original file called `lilo.conf.bak`.

IMPORTANT NOTE: This assumes that the system you are trying to boot will also recognize the new hard drive as `/dev/sda`.

Comment: The ancient kernel being booted will still recognize the drive as hda, so the root setting needs to stay as that, and only the boot setting needs to point to sda while reinstalling lilo from the livecd.