# Can't install Linux mint or boot into live cd! : " No Caching mode page found"

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

I'm trying to install Linux Mint xfce x86 on an old laptop that I have in my possession, but I keep getting an error when trying to boot into Live CD; it says:

`[sdb] No Caching mode page found`

`[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through`

And then it's just stuck there. The USB that I'm trying to install it off of does work (tried it on my Core 2 Duo machine) and it boots perfectly fine.

It doesn't work in compatibility mode, it just spits out a black screen after what looks like initialization of the live CD.

Comment: What is your graphic card model?

Comment: It's a GeForce 9300M GS

Comment: Try to boot with `nouveau.blacklist=1` and `acpi=off` parametres

Comment: see [KernelBootParameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) , past `nouveau.blacklist=1 acpi=off` before `quiet splash`

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, pnp 00:0c: unknown tag 0x0 length 0, pnp 00:0c: unknown tag 0x1 length 4, pnp 00:0c: no end tag in resource structure

Comment: and `nouveau.blacklist=1 nolapic`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot linux mint with `nouveau.blacklist=1 nolapic` parameters (see [KernelBootParameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) )

to permanently add the parameters after installing the system ,edit your `/etc/default/grub` change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

To

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.blacklist=1 nolapic quiet"
```

And update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: a little thing here, i keep getting 'failed to get canonical path of aufs' when running sudo update-grub, the only fix i found reinstalls grub and thus resetting the grub file, any possible fix to this?

Comment: follow this answer , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96981/153195 , use `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX` , instead of `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` . `sdX` is your hdd , also replace `sda6` with your root partition

Comment: @Tekunikaru are you solved your problem?

Comment: That doesnt seem to work either, running sudo updat-grub outputs `sudo: unable to resolve host mint: Connection refused` and `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).`, when running that grub install command you gave me it outputs `sudo: unable to resolve hostname mint: Connection refused`, `grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot (is /dev mounted?).`, `Installing for i386-pc platform` and `grub-install.real: error: cannot find a device for /mnt/boot/grub (is /dev mounted?).`, whats going on here?

Comment: Remove the kernel parametre and try to boot without it , just keep `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"` then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: I tried booting without the kernel parametre right after installing Linux Mint, no luck, it looks like a giant graphical glitch then an equal sign pops up then it does nothing for some reason

Comment: @Tekunikaru see https://askubuntu.com/a/868209 to blacklist `nouveau` from the terminal.

Comment: meh, this looks like too much work for something i'll barely use, i'll pass, thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: @Tekunikaru step 3 to 6

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the usb_live_boot disk booted fine on my newer laptop but wouldn't boot on a slightly older laptop.

The fix for me was to remove `persistent` from the boot string. So it was just `casper quiet splash`.

My 2¢.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, but underneath it was actually a problem with graphics drivers. I added `nomodeset` to boot options and booted successfully. For more information see https://askubuntu.com/questions/947830/errors-from-nouveau-when-installing-or-booting-from-live-usb