# /bin/bash Permission Denied

Tags: bash, permissions, mount, grub, chroot

I'm trying to install GRUB onto a separate partition who's volume shares a Windows installation. After having pulled, configured, and made GRUB, I can't `grub-mkconfig`. Doing some research, I found:  [grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96977/grub-probe-error-failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow?newreg=3173ed38987849d989c6b84919ba1e77) which is exactly my problem. Taking away that I need to chroot, but no matter what I do, I can't get permission for /bin/bash.

`sudo chroot /mnt` returns `/bin/bash: Permission denied`.

- `sudo chmod 777 /bin/bash` (and variations: `sudo chmod 777 .` , `sudo chmod 777 /mnt/bin/*`, etc.)
- `sudo chmod 755 /bin/bash` (and variations similar to above)
- `for dir in proc dev sys etc bin sbin var usr lib lib64 tmp; do
  sudo mkdir /mnt/chrootdir/$dir && sudo mount --bind /$dir /mnt/chrootdir/$dir`(I [followed this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow) which will explain where /mnt/chrootdir came from)
- /mnt/bin/bash exists

This isn't an installation of Ubuntu 18.04, just "trying" it. My process so far has been:

- Download grub
- Download stuff grub needs (flex, bison, gcc)
- `./configure`
- `make`
- `sudo mount /grub/partition /mnt`
- `grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --force`
- `grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg` <-- "Cannot get canonical path for /cow" which led me to the earlier link.

What am I doing wrong? I tried doing my due diligence so I apologize for making another thread related to this (there seems to be a ton of them) but I really am lost.

Comment: Hi Harin, can you clarify this question a little bit? Have a look at the information in the StackOverflow help (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I'd suggest starting by 1) describing what you want to accomplish, and 2) explaining the problem you're experiencing (/bin/bash not available in chroot) including any errors it's giving you followed by 3) what you've tried. It's not common to configure and make grub, rather than install from apt (`sudo apt install grub-pc` or `sudo apt install grub-efi` depending on your system).

Comment: I want to add GRUB to Windows via a separate partition. The way I've found is best is by using gParted to create a separate partition for GRUB (after having installed Windows) then doing what I described above.

Once I get GRUB working, I plan to use my Windows + GRUB VM to debug GRUB because I need to extend its functionality. So, while it's not common to configure and make grub, I will need to do that in the long run when I add my functionality to it. I'm currently just trying to be able to step through unmodified GRUB to get the hang of using GDB and this new dev environment.

Comment: Your question makes it sound like you are installing grub onto a disk with Windows. It is not clear that this disk also has a Linux partition. Does this disk also have a Linux partition? You are supposed to be chrooting into a partition with a Linux installation on it. Otherwise, you are not doing what the instructions you linked to are for.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. I do not have a Linux installation as I am trying to do all this without having to install Linux. Is there a way to do this without having a Linux installation?